# Casting a null character reference ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

In C# .net, if I take a `string.Empty` and call `.FirstOrDefault()` on it, intending to get the first character of the string, It will return a null character reference i.e. `\0`, and not a null character i.e. `char?`. Then casting this ToString() does not have the same value as `string.Empty`

So based on my testing the following statements appear to resolve to true:

`string.Empty.FirstOrDefault().ToString() != string.Empty`

`((char?)null).ToString() == string.Empty`

`string.Empty.FirstOrDefault().ToString() == '\0'.ToString()`

Is it just me or does this feel inconsistent? This wasn't obvious to me initially and I had assumed that `string.Empty.FirstOrDefault().ToString()` would resolve to the same value as `string.Empty`. Can anybody link me to documentation that covers this gotcha in more depth?

Comment: What does `string.Empty.FirstOrDefault()` return? Why do you think that is? Also, create an empty array of ints called `bob`. What would `bob.FirstOrDefault()` return, and why?

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but then why does `'\0'.ToString() != string.Empty`?

Comment: I have an egg container in one hand, with no eggs in it. I have another egg container with one egg in it, but that egg has no yolk. Do those two egg containers have the same contents? I have a string with no characters in it. I have a string with a (admittedly odd) character in it. Are those two strings equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, so `FirstOrDefault()` on an empty string returns `default(char)`, not `default(char?)`.

`default(char)` is `'\0'`.

It is (almost) impossible to write a generic method that works on references types but returns `T?` for value types (which is what you're expecting here).

Comment: I like this answer a lot, and testing with default(char) eventually led me to a path of learning this lesson today. But I still feel like I do not fully grasp the idea. Take my vote, but I'm waiting for links to docs before accepting any specific answer.

Comment: Links to docs about which feature? Nullable types? Generics? Default values for primitive types?

Comment: I guess what really confuse me is why a string of nullable characters would not match the value of a string.Empty. This is where I'm struggling to understand

Comment: Think you want  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2                                                                    String implements IEnumerable<char>

Comment: The docs alas don't cover everything that every possible person can't understand @Oxymoron. The problem here is that your mental model is wrong. You are asking 'why are these two different things not equal' and the answer, oddly, is that they aren't equal.

Comment: @mjwills You're right. I had a misconception of what string.Empty actually was!

Comment: *"why a string of nullable characters would not match the value of a string.Empty"* because `string.Empty` has *no* characters. You are asking for First**OrDefault**, and are getting `default(char)` back (because there is no "First"). `string.Empty != "\0"`

Comment: so if string.Empty has no characters, is it like `char[0]` an empty a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ enumerable of characters?

Comment: @Oxymoron: Yes; that's exactly what it is.

Comment: I wonder if [the source code for the string class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c) is the documentation you're looking for?

Comment: So let me get this straight - a collection of null characters does not equal the absence of characters?

Comment: @Oxymoron correct. A null character is a character.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Read the first paragraph of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/ @Oxymoron.

Comment: @Oxymoron: I think there is a nomenclature problem here. We historically refer to the character with code zero as "the null character", but that has nothing whatsoever to do with the value `null`, either as a reference, or as the default value of a nullable value type. It is just a historical accident that character zero is called "the null character".

Comment: @Oxymoron: The reason for this oddity is: in C#, all strings know their own lengths, but there are historical string management systems where strings do not know their own length; by convention, we say that the string ends when you encounter the first null character. In languages that use those conventions, *the empty string is the string that consists of a single null character*.  **C# is not such a language**. In C#, strings know their own lengths, and an empty string is a string with no characters.

Answer (score 3):

1. `string.Empty` = `""` is array of chars of length `0`.
2. `string.Empty.FirstOrDefault()` is `default(char)` which is `'\0'` *(`FirstOrDefault<T>` returns `default(T)` if source is empty)*
3. `string.Empty.FirstOrDefault().ToString()` = `default(char).ToString()` = `"\0"`
4. `char?` is `Nullable<char>`, if you check `ToString()` implementation for `Nullable`

---

```
public override string ToString()
{
  if (!this.hasValue)
    return "";
  return this.value.ToString();
}
```

which means, `((char?)null).ToString()` returns `""` (or `string.Empty`).